# windows command line javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, command-line

I'm *trying* to run javascript from a windows command line via script

cscript //NoLogo test.js

However, I can't find any predefined objects which are available.  I'm totally at a loss - Can't get hello world to work:

`System.print("Hello, World!")`

results in `"System" is undefined`

Is there another way I should be running this - like through .NET runtime?

Thanks

jeff

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the Windows Scripting Host.

You can say things like:

```
WScript.Echo("Hello, World.");
```

It's all COM-based, so you instantiate ActiveX controls to do anything useful:

```
var y = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary");
y.add ("a", "test");
if (y.Exists("a"))
   WScript.Echo("true");
```

Or:

```
var fso, f1;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
// Get a File object to query.
f1 = fso.GetFile("c:\\detlog.txt");   
// Print information.
Response.Write("File last modified: " + f1.DateLastModified);
```

See [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to run JavaScript in a shell, then you should consider installing Node.js

http://javascript.cs.lmu.edu/notes/commandlinejs/

Comment: It's so funny... this question was asked before NodeJS was even a thing. :') Had no idea what the accepted answer was talking about until I saw the date. How times change...

Answer (score 4):

That is actually JScript and when run with `cscript` or `wscript`, it's under the Windows Scripting Host environment, which has no real similarity with web-based javascript.

[Windows Scripting Host reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try `WScript`:

```
WScript.Echo('hello world');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very outdated thread, many of the answers are incomplete and/or simply don't work. The way to run JS in shell (regardless if you're using windows or not), is to use *Node.js*. After you have installed Node, you use it from command line, like this:

```
$ node
> console.log('Hello, world');
Hello, world
undefined
> .exit
```

or from a file:

```
$ cat hello.js
#!/usr/bin/node
console.log('Hello, world');

$ ./hello.js
Hello, world
```

Or from node itself:

```
$ node hello.js
Hello, world
```

Comment: While it's old and the documentation is more sparse by the day, a lot can be accomplished on a Windows machine by scripts written using WSH + JScript, including compiling to a small, portable executable file. Node.js + NPM have Win32 libraries and can probably accomplish all of the same end goals, but there will certainly be a difference in the "weights" of the solution. The Windows Node.js executable alone was about 50mb at the time of writing this comment.