# Javascript: permission denied

Tags: javascript

I've followed this tutorial for Rabbitmq in Javascript. 
These are the codes:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/javascript-nodejs/src/send.js

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/javascript-nodejs/src/receive.js

But, when I try to run them with *./send.js* and/or *./recv.js* it gives me "Permission denied" error.

I look for some solutions but I don't understand, or I find something about IE (that it's not my case) - plus I don't think the problem is the browser (?) If it's so... why? :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run JavaScript files from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659778/is-it-possible-to-run-javascript-files-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

Well, i think you are wrong with few things... you are trying to run it without node or an interpreter.

- If a file it's not a module like file, you should use `node ./file.js`
- If a file it's a module you must to use something like this `var myModule = require('./myModule.js);` and use its functions.
- If a file it's a browser script you should use like this `<script src="/file.js"></script>` and use its functions.

I don't know that software and how it works, but that are the essentials usages of common javascript files.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try! This is the first time I use Javascript, I didn't know that... :D

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run Javascript from the command line. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28756251/270847) details how to do it with Node, with instructions from [Command Line Javascript](http://javascript.cs.lmu.edu/notes/commandlinejs/). Here's a quick rundown:

- [Download and install Node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki)
- Create the file hello.js containing just one line:
  `console.log('Hello, world');`
- Running your program is easy; invoke node on the file containing your program:
  `node hello.js`